# Slicing 2d array from values in 1d array onwards

Tags: python, numpy

Having an arbitrary 2d array, say of zeros, and an array of indices:

```
z = np.zeros((5,5))
ix = np.array([1,4,2,3,0])
```

How could I add a `1` from the columns specified by a 1d array onwards, in order to obtain:

```
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I have not been able to find a simple way of doing so using `numpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be -

```
In [50]: ncols = 5

In [51]: (ix[:,None] <= np.arange(ncols)).view('i1')
Out[51]: 
array([[0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int8)
```

If you have to add to an existing array `z` -

```
z += (ix[:,None] <= np.arange(ncols))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Pretty nice solution. One doubt, what is the reason of using `view`
 here rather than say `astype`?

Comment: @yatu Just for memory efficiency and hence performance, being a view.

Comment: Ah of course, `astype` is creating a copy of the array. Got it, thanks!